# Python / statsmodels - out of sample predictions

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels, autoregressive-models

I am trying to perform autoregressive multiple linear regressions using statsmodels (something like `y ~ y_1 + X1 + X2`, not ARMA-like).
More specifically, I'm looking for a way to get out of sample results.
When I use the predict method, I get *in sample* results which means that it uses the previous **historical value** of the estimated variable instead of the **estimated value** of the variable.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `y_1 * X1 + X2` probably?

Comment: Not really, to be more specific it has this (formal) form:
y = constant + y_lagged1*a0 + X1*a1 + X2*a2

Comment: There is no automatic support. If y_i is the lagged value, then you need to loop over each period and create the regressor matrix for predict for forecasting several periods.

Comment: OK, quite disappointing as it is very useful to assess predictive power of the model. Thansk for your feedback!